# What will happen in SQL, when the WHERE clause is fed with a NULL condition?

Tags: sql, null

How many tuples does the result of the following SQL query contain?

```
SELECT A.Id FROM A 
WHERE A.Age > ALL(NULL)
```

A consist of 4 tuples, and ID is a Primary key.

Should the answer be 4, or 0?

Comment: Can't you just execute it and check the result?

Comment: Did you try it? What do you think the results of `ALL(NULL)` will be? Based on your answer to that, how many records will match `A.Age > ALL(NULL)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is going to return no rows.

Why?  You are confusing `NULL` with the empty set.  You have a single value that you are comparing to.  The value is `NULL`.  Almost any comparison is going to be `NULL` -- which is treated as false.  So, the query returns no rows.

This is quite different from an empty set.  If there are no rows in the set of values, then the query will return all rows.  For instance:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM (VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4)) a(id, age)
WHERE A.Age > ALL (SELECT 0 WHERE 1=0);
```

Comment: Hi, you are absolutely correct. But, I need one more help can you please elaborate why in case of empty set it returns all rows? I mean, I really want to know the reason, been stuck on this for quite a while now...

Comment: @NeelMishra . . . Because any value, say 5, is greater than all values in a set that is empty.